# ssh and character encoding

Tags: ssh, character-encoding, locale

When I `ssh` into my VPS, I have `irssi` running in screen. When someone sends a unicode character (such as © or €), `irssi` displays garbage when I use it via the screen in a `ssh` session. If I connect to that `irssi` using irssi's proxy module, from irssi running on my local computer, it shows up correctly.

Likewise, if I run ghci on my VPS (outside a screen) and enter in one of those characters, it crashes.

So, obviously, there is a character encoding issue of some sort with my connection to my VPS, either in ssh or the system setup.

How can I find out what is causing this, and solve it?

Details:

**Client system**

- Arch Linux x64
- UTF-8 encoding

**VPS system**

- Ubuntu Server 10.04
- Unknown encoding used. How do I find this? (I just have to look in my /etc/rc.conf for Arch)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Running the `locale` command will give you information about your locale settings; the character encoding is given by the `LC_CTYPE` setting.

Under Ubuntu, the default locale settings are given in `/etc/default/locale`. You can change the character encoding by setting `LC_CTYPE` in your `~/.profile` on the VPS, e.g.

```
export LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8
```

You'll have to make sure that the `en_US.UTF-8` locale is available. Ubuntu only generates locale data for requested locales. All English locales should be available if you have the package `language-pack-en-base` installed. You can manually request their generation with

```
sudo locale-gen en
```

You can also add entries to `/var/lib/locales/supported.d/local` to make sure a particular locale is installed (e.g., add the line `en_US.UTF-8 UTF-8`).

Answer (score 7):

actally the value given in LC_CTYPE is a locale *name*.
It is customary, but not required, that the charset encoding be in the name.

But if you want to know, for sure, the charset, then the command is `locale -k charmap`.

```
~$ LC_CTYPE=C locale -k charmap
charmap="ANSI_X3.4-1968"
~$ LC_CTYPE=fr_BE locale -k charmap
charmap="ISO-8859-1"
```

(note how the charset doesn't appear on the LC_TYPE values above).